# How many disc revolutions make 1kWh on this kWh-meter?

Tags: power-meter

This a kWh meter from a TV show. I'd like to know how many disc revolutions make 1 kWh. I think it's somehow coded in the whole data on the panel or could be derived from that information:

[image: KwH meter]

I found a formula

P = (3600 * Kh) / t

(t = time in seconds taken by the disc to complete one revolution, P = power in watts)

which gives me 138,(8) revolutions per 1 kWh but I am not sure I used the formula correctly.

Comment: The Rr 13 8/9 is the speed in rpm at full load.

Comment: @PlasmaHH And how much is full load?

Comment: probably 200A (cl200) but I am not sure, I don't much about US meters.

Comment: Strange. It's usually stated in clear text revolutions/kWh and not related to full load. Can you by any chance find a datasheet for it?

Comment: Googling around I found this which should answer all your questions and raise a ton more: https://www.usbr.gov/power/data/fist/fist3_10/vol3-10.pdf

Comment: it's a GE "I-70-S" I cant see the gear ratio mentioned anywhere. unless it's 13\$8\over9\$ right in the middle

Comment: From the document referenced by PlasmaHH above, 3.9.1. Watt-hour constant (Kh). The watt-hour constant isWh the registration of one revolution of the rotating disk element expressed in watt-hours. - 
Kh = 7.2 - 1 revolution = 7.2Wh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Kh is (indeed) what you're after, and the formula you give seems to be correct, [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_meter), 'Electromechanical' section.

P = (3600 * Kh) / t         *(for one rotation)*

If we call the amount of rotations n, we get (P / n) = (3600 * Kh) / t

Or: P = (3600 * Kh) / (t * n)

Where:

```
    t = Time in seconds
    P = Power in Watts
```

That means the unit of Kh is:

- (W / n) = (3600 * Kh) / s
- (3600 * Kh) = W / (n * s)
- Kh = W / (n * s * 3600)
- And because s * 3600 = 1 hour: Kh = W / (h * n)

*So if Kh = 7.2, and it takes 1 hour for the dial to rotate 1 time, you've used 7.2 Watts.*

You want (n * kWh). Let's change that into (n * Wh) for now.

- Divide everything on the right side through W: Kh = 1 / (Wh * n)
- (n * Wh) = 1 / Kh

Now, we need to change Wh to kWh, so we multiply both sides with 1000:

- (n * kWh) = 1000 / Kh

So for Kh = 7.2 you get 138.89 n*kWh or 138.89 rotations per kWh.

Your calculation is correct. :-)